# How to achieve Workbench studio light in EEVEE and Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, workbench-render-engine

In Workbench studio light. The light and shadow is at the same corner whatever we rotate the object.

I guess I need to use a texture and emission instead of adding a light.
Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. Render a ball as a MatCap using Workbench. Use the MatCap in EEVEE and Cycles.

*It works but it might be slightly brighter than workbench. Because workbench also use material color or single color. The default of them is 0.8 brightness white, not 1.

[image](Render MatCap using Workbench)

[image](Result Check via Monkey Head)

[image]

!!! I forgot to add an emission node before connecting to material output:(